# Why does the <style> tag in HTML take a type attribute?

Tags: html

I mean does anyone use a value different than "text/css"?

Comment: The `type` attribute is by the way not required anymore in HTML5 doctype. It defaults to `text/css`. The same applies on `<script>` which defaults to `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CSS and JavaScript might have killed all their rivals and dominated the browser, but other languages have existed, and the victory of CSS/JS was much less certain when HTML 4 was being written.

For stylesheets, the only real contender was JSSS, which saw support in Netscape 4 (which had really poor CSS support due to it being an emulation layer over its JSSS engine).

Answer (score 2):

There is text/xsl. It is also good design to make it possible to add new alternative style types in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What if someone creates a new, better "stylesheet language"? Change the HTML specification?

I would say, this is an application of [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).